# How to require a chinese named ruby file?

Tags: ruby, watir

How to require a chinese named ruby file, for example require '测试'！

Comment: Why would anyone use any language other than English to name source code files? That's just torture.

Comment: Which ruby version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using Chinese characters to name files?

I would highly recommend against that. From my experience contemporary software (including operating systems) does not handle such files correctly in most cases.

Comment: thank you for your answer, because use chinese named file will more easy to identify. And I was use the silktest it support this.

Answer (score 2):

> How to require a chinese named ruby file, for example `require '测试'`！

Just

```
require '测试'
```

Why would the language of the filename matter anyway?

Comment: my project code is set 'utf-8',and if require '测试', there is a error:<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- 测试 (LoadError)
 from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
 from D:/WatirWebDriver/netbeans/WatirTest/lib/r����.rb:3:in `<main>'

Comment: Is the directory the file is in on the `$LOAD_PATH`? Does the file actually exist?